# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygam'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygam

I'm trying to execute a python script which **pygam** ( **from pygam import LogisticGAM, LinearGAM**
).

when I'm trying to execute this script  I have this error:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygam'**

The problem that `pygam` is installed with both `pip` and `pip3`.

This the result when I try to re-install it using **pip**:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: The directory '/home/mobelite/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/home/mobelite/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pygam in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pygam) (1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pygam) (0.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pygam) (1.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: progressbar2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pygam) (3.47.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from progressbar2->pygam) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-utils>=2.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from progressbar2->pygam) (2.3.0)
```

and this is the result when I try to re-install them using **pip3**:

```
The directory '/home/mobelite/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/mobelite/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pygam in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): future in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from pygam)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): progressbar2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from pygam)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pygam)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pygam)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-utils>=2.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from progressbar2->pygam)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from progressbar2->pygam)
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I found this is normal because I just install it, but I don't understand why they don't see **pygam**

Comment: Are you sure that you installed it for the same Python installation on which you try to use it?

Comment: Yes, I install it using both pip and pip3, and also I tried to run the script using python and python 3 also, but I have the same issue:(

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Make sure you are not using virtual environment, you must install **pygame**, just run the following command:

```
pip install pygame
```

Install it and try again. More information visit https://pypi.org/project/pygame/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the right versions of python and pip.
Try installing it again with python (with the correct version) you are using to run the script.
For example, you want to run it with [yhon3.5 use the below command:

```
python3.5 -m pip install pygam
```

I am assuming `python3.5` in the above command invokes `Python 3.5`, on my system I have `python3` invoke `Python 3.5`

Give the install a try with `sudo` as well

```
sudo pip install pygam
# OR
sudo pip3 install pygam
```

`pip -V` command will you the currently running version of pip and the python version it is installed in.
Example:

```
pip -V
 pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

pip3 -V
 pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

The above comes handy if multiple versions of python are installed on a system.
Let us know if it helps.

Comment: What about this in the traceback: `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7` ? Is there anyway to solve it with Python 2.7?

Comment: @CeliusStingher if I understand your question correctly, that is a deprecation warning by Python because it will end support on January 1st, 2020. It has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @AmitYadav the issue is not fixed yet. this is the result of                       
**which python3 : /usr/bin/python3 ** 
**which pip  : /usr/local/bin/pip**
**which pip3 : /usr/bin/pip3**
and always I have the same output when I try to install pygam  or to re-executethe script using python3 or python

Comment: what does *pip3 -V* say?

Comment: @AmitYadav  pip3 -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)

Comment: @CeliusStingher try upgrading `pip` once and then install `pygam` again. To upgrade `pip`, run this command: `pip3 install --upgrade pip`. Let us know if this works!